# AWS EC2 Instance - Is it a single virtual image or single physical machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, autoscaling

Sorry, I had a few basic questions. I'm planning to use an AWS EC2 instance.

```
1) Is an EC2 instance a single virtual machine image or is it a
single physical machine? Documentation from Amazon states that it is
a "virtual server", but I wanted to clarify if it is an image
embedded inside one server or if it is an single physical server
itself.

2) Is an Elastic Load Balancer a single EC2 instance that handles
all requests from all users and simply forwards the request to the
least loaded EC2 instances?

3) When Auto-Scaling is enabled for an EC2 instance, does it simply
exactly replicate the original EC2 instance when it needs to scale
up?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is a virtual server, a VM, as stated in the documentation.
2. It's a little more complicated that that, based on the way AWS might scale the load balancer, or create a version in each availability zone, etc. It also provides more features such as auto-scaling integration, health checks, SSL termination. I suggest you [read the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).
3. It uses a machine image that you specify when you create the auto-scaling group (when you create the Launch Configuration used by the Auto-scaling group to be more precise). A common practice is to configure a machine image that will download any updates and launch the latest version of your application on startup.

You might also be interested in [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) which is a PaaS that manages much of the AWS infrastructure for you. There are also third-party PaaS offerings such as OpenShift and Heroku that also manage AWS resources for you.

Answer (score 3):

1. An EC2 instance is a VM that gets some percentage of the underlying physical host's RAM, CPU, disk, and network i/o. That percentage could theoretically be 100% for certain instance types, including bare-metal instances, but is typically some fraction depending on which instance type you choose.
2. ELB is a service, not a single EC2 instance. It will scale on your behalf. It routes by round robin for TCP, and routes on fewest outstanding requests for HTTP and HTTPS.
3. Auto Scaling is "scale out" (it adds new EC2 instances), not "scale up" (resizing an existing EC2 instance). It launches a new instance from a template called an AMI.